# JTable value being overwritten

Tags: java, swing

My GUI application is Connecting to the DB and I have managed to add a product from the DB to my JTable on the GUI. When I click a second button it overwrites the first. I do not want this as it is an order till system and I want whatever I click to appear on the table as it is clicked. Is there any way to append onto the table rather than overwriting the values every time. Here is my code.

```
americanoSmall.addActionListener(
        new ActionListener()
        {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
            {
                try {
                    String query = "select ProductName, Price from product where ProductID = 24";
                    java.sql.PreparedStatement pst = connection.prepareStatement(query);
                    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
                    table.setModel(DbUtils.resultSetToTableModel(rs));

                    } catch (Exception e1) 
                    {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: Instead of replacing the table model, just add onto the one that's already there.

Comment: *"Is there any way to append onto the table rather than overwriting the values every time"* - Yes, get your hands dirty. Basically, take the value(s) you are getting from the database, wrap them some kind of POJO (plain old java object) and add them to a `TableModel` capable of managing them. This is a basic concept of the `JTable` and `TableModel` APIs.  I'd refrain from using things like `DbUtils` and `DefaultTableModel` which take over control of managing the data structures, as is all to common, you need more capability than they provide

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't change the `table model` whenever the model changes. Instead, use the `addRow` method of the `TableModel`. Here's a minimal, complete and verifiable example.

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Test");

        Container cont = frame.getContentPane();
        cont.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        DefaultTableModel dtm = new DefaultTableModel(new Object[]{"Column 1","Column 2"}, 0);
        JTable table = new JTable(dtm);

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(table);
        cont.add(scroll, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        dtm.addRow(new Object[]{"Value 1", "Value 2"});

        JButton add = new JButton("Add");
        cont.add(add, BorderLayout.NORTH);

        add.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                dtm.addRow(new Object[]{"Another value", "Another value"});
            }
        });

        frame.pack();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You, it adds to it now instead of overwriting it. How would i pull the contents from the DB though, like ProductName and Price?

Comment: I dont want to hard code the values of each item, i want to pull them from the DB dynamically from the SQL query

Comment: @Movillian As described in your [previous question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43076871/jtable-wont-populate-when-clicking-jbutton), the `TableModel` is representation of the data, how you wrap that depends on a number of factors, as I suggested, you could actually make use of the database `ResultSet` itself, or you could build a representation of POJO (plain old java objects) and maintain them in some kind of `List`. How you do this to meet your needs is beyond the scope of the question or even SO, what you are been presented with are ideas you need to adapt to your needs

Comment: @Movillian, as MadProgrammer described, I have only presented you with an example that shows how you modify the table model, without having to reset it. Now, it's up to you how you pull the data and populate the table model.

Comment: @Movillian `Thank You, it adds to it now instead of overwriting it.` - then your original question has been answered. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved.

Comment: Thank You. Its working very well for me now. Thank You for all your guidance.